# JavaScript callback style - Moving to promises

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work out how I can do my JavaScript callbacks in a different style.

My current style of callback, passes the callback into the function, and the function calls the callback. For example:

**Function call**

```
doSomething(function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

**Function**

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    // Call the callback
    callback("someData");
}
```

This is the current style of callback that I'm using. But I've seen libraries that do their callbacks in a different style. For example:

**Function call**

```
doSomething().success(function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

How does this work, and could anybody outline a simple example for me? Thanks for your time.

Comment: "I've seen libraries that do their callbacks in a different style" - example?

Comment: I did mean doSomething().success(...), I'll update the question to reflect that, thanks

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I meant a real-world example — I’m assuming there isn’t an actual library with a `doSomething()` function :)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Ah.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an implementation of the promise library. [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) has an implementation called deferreds and another one is [Q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/).

`doSomething` would look like something like this, using jQuery.

```
function doSomething() {
   var dfd = $.deferred();
   // do your logic
   // eventually call dfd.resolve();
   return dfd.promise();
}
```

Then calling it, use

```
doSomething().then(function() {
   // do something else
});
```

What is nice about this pattern, is that you can have multiple callbacks and error callbacks.

Comment: @GDownes i do not think so, `Q` can be used with node.

Answer (score 3):

The style that you're describing is generally called promises. jQuery has promises, but their documentation calls them ["Deferreds"](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and it is an implementation of the [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) spec; there are a couple other promises libraries out there, including [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). (YUI also contains a promises implementation.)

There have been a bunch of recent (mid-2013) blog posts about promises, so it should be easy to find more information about them, both as a pattern and about specific implementations. It's worth digging into the source code of a couple of the implementations to see the nuts-and-bolts, but at a high-level, you can think of promises like this:

- You wrap an asynchronous function in a promise and it is called.
- The promise itself is then returned, meaning that you can save a reference to it in a variable.
- The promise itself will be resolved (or "fulfilled") when the async function you called is complete.
- You can then call `done` on the resolved promises, passing your callback function as the argument to `done`.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it simply this here:

**Function**

```
doSomething = new Object();

doSomething.success = function(callback) {
    // Call the callback
    callback("someData");
}
```

So it is just an Object extended with a member "success" that is a function.

Comment: Nope. In the OP’s example, `doSomething` is a function, not an object.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: But not in the initial version of his post. Seems he forgot the braces.. `doSomething.success()` http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17613225/1

Comment: I don't see `doSomething = new Object();` in that revision.

Comment: `doSOmething` will be an Object at latest if you add another function to it. If you do `doSomething.success()` you call the member function `success` of the Object `doSomething`

Comment: Right, but `doSomething` *wasn't* an object in the example, it was a function.

Comment: (Almost) everything is an Object. And as long as you do not call a Function via `()`, the Function will be treated as Object.

Comment: Sure, but your answer didn't describe it as a function that wasn't called. Your answer suggested it was just a regular object.

Comment: Okay, I get it, thought about using a shortcut when writing it. I'll remove the post in a few days/hours anyway. It doesn't answer the question as it is written right now.